# Sprint network interfering with mobile site?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I know it sounds crazy but I'm sitting here with various phone on different networks and all the phones on the sprint network are failing to work correctly.

It looks as if the LESS style sheet is not being applied. Has any one ever ran into any thing like this?

Also just visited the LESS website figuring all there styles would be created with LESS and its doing the same thing. Failing to load/apply the LESS.

The specific phones I have tried on the sprint network are two iphones and one android optimus V.

Comment: I have confirmed that it is loading and executing the less.js on my server by adding alerts at top and bottom of the file.

Comment: Just a thought, have you put the script tag that loads LESS after the link tag to the less sheet? Also, have you made sure your link tag uses `rel="stylesheet/less"`? I'm wondering if you've adhered to all the usage guidelines as per http://lesscss.org/#usage

Comment: I just double checked and I am indeed placing the less style sheet before the less js call and using stylesheet/less as the rel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest pre-processing your LESS file into CSS and serving that on your site.

It is considerably more efficient as even a medium sized less file can take hundreds of milliseconds to process during page load. It is also one less javascript file to download in production. Finally, it is a lot less processor overhead on mobile devices that need to not only parse the javascript, but then parse the less file as well. Some mobile devices don't have caching or local storage so there is a potential for them to be re-processing the less file every time the page loads.

Either use the lessc compiler (requires Node.js) or [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) to pre-compile your css files.

Comment: That is the ideal case. Right now we are changing it rapidly and I dont like the idea of the less being not required to make style changes. I'm searching for some php that will compile them on the fly but only if the cached file is out of date with the less. I mainly wanted to bring this to peoples attention that sprints network is doing some thing weird with data.

Comment: If it is any sort of production environment, you should be pre-compiling no matter what. This doesn't have to be a manual process. Just do it as part of your deployment script on the server.

Comment: Just so every one who finds this knows. I was able to work around this by using php to convert the less to css on the fly and cache it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to see if it's blocking the download of the less javascript or the stylesheet itself by loading their URLs directly.

For lesscss.org that would be http://lesscss.org/less/main.less and http://lesscss.org/js/less.js

Comment: Good call. I tried loading both directly in the browser on the phones but both files load fine. So it must have some thing to do with how there embedded or how its loading the less file.

I'm going to try and add a quick alert to my less.js and see if that gets run.

Comment: I spotted that main.less is being delivered with a text/plain MIME type. Not sure if that's enough to upset anything.

Comment: I have thought about trying to have apache deliver it as different MIME type to see if that helps. I should have time to give that a try today.